# Cloud Composer Service Account Scope For Running Services within GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am setting up a DAG in Cloud Composer that triggers a number of Cloud Run and Cloud Function services. The service account specified in the Cloud Composer Environment (a user created SA) definitely has permissions to invoke both Cloud Run and Cloud Function services, however the Cloud Run functions are giving the following error:

```
The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating
```

The tasks are like so:

```
#t1 as request first report
big3_request = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id= "big3_request",
    method='GET',
    http_conn_id='trigger_cloud_run_service_conversions_big_3',
    endpoint='',
    response_check = lambda response: True if response == ("ok", 200) else False
)
```

I would have thought that the cloud composer environment would be able to use the service accounts IAM roles, but this doesn't seem to be the case. What do I need to do here to enable the services to run? It looks like I can add the keyfile of the service account to the connection, but I don't see why this should be necessary if the same service account is used in the CC environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service (your `SimpleHttpOperator`  task running in cloud composer) needs to provide authentication credentials in the request. More precisely it needs to

> add a Google-signed OpenID Connect ID token as part of the request

You can find [here in the official Google doc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#acquire-token), different methods to provide such token and a proper request to your Cloud Run service endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the code in the docs you linked to in a PythonOperator task, rather than a SimpleHttpOperator task, to generate the token and call the url. Seems to be working nicely now.